# Weight painting blue texture glitching

Tags: interface, weight-painting

My problem is that in weight painting even for a simple cube the texture is glitching Any idea what can cause this to happen? (The different colors are from actually painting on it so it works it just glitches out with the stripes or other shapes)

To specify and narrow it down, it does this when it tries to apply another "layer" on the original, for example weight paint, "show overlays--> face orientation", Edit mode.

It does work perfectly fine, if a material is applied to it or even in texture paint.

Also if I use cycles renderer for the weight paint it is working as intended, but this is not an option on the long run to paint in cycles.

Edit it does this with all the versions back to 2.83.16

[image: FaceOrientation]
[image: Simple cube weight paint]
[image: Cycles proper render]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this instead of the developer forum, because it is well hidden to say, this issue is known but not fixed if I am correct
[developer forum](https://developer.blender.org/T87927#1189650)